# Reading directly from Google Drive in Java

Tags: java, file-io, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Please I need to read the content of a file stored in Google Drive programmatically. I'm looking forward to some sort of 
`InputStream is = <drive_stuff>.read(fileID);` 
Any help?
I'll also appreciate if I can write back to a file using some sort of

`OutputStream dos = new DriveOutputStream(driveFileID);` 
`dos.write(data);`

If this sort of convenient approach is too much for what Drive can offer, please I'll like to have suggestions on how I can read/write to Drive directly from java.io.InputStream / OutputStream / Reader / Writer without creating temporary local file copies of the data I want to ship to drive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

// Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();

```
    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
         .execute();

    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            String fileId = file.getId();

                Export s=service.files().export(fileId, "text/plain");
                InputStream in=s.executeMediaAsInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;

                StringBuilder responseData = new StringBuilder();
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseData.append(line);
                }
                System.out.println(responseData);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add a comment to the script and included the first two lines inside the code

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the DrEdit Java sample that is available on the Google Drive SDK [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java).
This example shows how to authorize and build requests to read metadata, file's data and upload content to Google Drive.

Here is a code snippet showing how to use the `ByteArrayContent` to upload media to Google Drive stored in a byte array:

```
/**
 * Create a new file given a JSON representation, and return the JSON
 * representation of the created file.
 */
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {
  Drive service = getDriveService(req, resp);
  ClientFile clientFile = new ClientFile(req.getReader());
  File file = clientFile.toFile();

  if (!clientFile.content.equals("")) {
    file = service.files().insert(file,
        ByteArrayContent.fromString(clientFile.mimeType, clientFile.content))
        .execute();
  } else {
    file = service.files().insert(file).execute();
  }

  resp.setContentType(JSON_MIMETYPE);
  resp.getWriter().print(new Gson().toJson(file.getId()).toString());
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide code to download from drive? I've made several attempts I got checkered by so many things (one was a MediaUnsupportedException). How do I download from Drive programatically in Java?

Comment: Please have a thorough look in our documentation and reference guide, this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) already have an example of how to download a file's content in multiple languages including Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (incomplete) snippet from my app which might help.

```
            URL url = new URL(urlParam);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection
                .setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                        "OAuth "+accessToken);

        String docText = convertStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I wonder why one has to go through this sort of heavy-lifting just to perform simple tasks. I think the official API lacks a lot of key functionalities. I had to write a personal mini library to address many of them for convenience. I'm currently thinking of writing an advanced Drive API on top of the current Drive Java API to shield developers from this sort of mundane stuffs for common tasks. For example, an ability to DFS one's entire Drive in search for mp3 files might be a good feature. If there are a lot of people who would like this, I can make a general API out of it.

Comment: It's not too bad. A small handful of convenience methods in a mediator class, and you're good to go.

My snippet calls the HTTP REST API directly. Google do offer a higher level abstraction with the Java client library. However my experience of using it hasn't been great, which is why I prefer to work with the API directly.

Comment: Exactly. For example, I couldn't get the Drive#files().get().download(OutputStream) method to work properly. I've had a painful experience with that thing.

Comment: @pinoyyid can you help me, i have create client id for google drive app,now i want create android app which will show me my google drive files and folder, please help me, i am just a beginner. i would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Using google-api-services-drive-v3-rev24-java-1.22.0: 
To read the contents of a file, make sure you set `DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY` when you do `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(...)` in your credential authorizing method/code.

You'll need the `fileId` of the file you want to read.  You can do something like this:
`FileList result = driveService.files().list().execute();`
You can then iterate the `result` for the `file` and `fileId` you want to read.

Once you have done that, reading the contents would be something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```